# Insert geometry point mysql from pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am using pandas and a Dataframe to deal with some data. I want to load the data into a mySQL dabase where one of the fields is a Point.

In the file I am parsing with python I have the lat and lon of the points.

I have created a dataframe (df) with the point information (id and coords):

```
id   coords
 A  GeomFromText( ' POINT(40.87 3.80) ' )
```

I have saved in coords the command required in mySQL to create a Point from the text. However, when executing:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(dbconnection)

df.to_sql("point_test",engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

I got the following error:

> DataError: (mysql.connector.errors.DataError) 1416 (22003): Cannot get
>   geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
>
> Triggered because df.to_sql transforms the GeomFromText( ' POINT(40.87
>   3.80) ' ) into string as "GeomFromText( ' POINT(40.87 3.80) ' )" when it should be the execution of the function GeomFromText in mySQL.

Does anyone has a suggestion about how to insert in mySQL geometrical fields information originally in text form using pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to create a temporary table with the String of the geometrical information that need to be added and then update the point_test table with a call to ST_GeomFromText from the temporary table.

Assuming database with table point_test with id (VARCHAR(5)) and coords(POINT):

a.Create dataframe df as an example with point "A" and "B"

```
dfd = np.array([['id','geomText'],
            ["A","POINT( 50.2 5.6 )"],
            ["B","POINT( 50.2 50.4 )"]])

df=pd.DataFrame(data=dfd[1:,:], columns=dfd[0,:])
```

b.Add point "A" and "B" into point_test but only the id and add the string "geomText" into the table temp_point_test

```
df[['id']].to_sql("point_test",engine, index=False, if_exists="append")

df[['id', 'geomText']].to_sql("temp_point_test",engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

c. Update table point_test with the point from table temp_point_test applying the ST_GeomFromText() to the select. Finally, drop temp_point_test:

```
conn = engine.connect()

conn.execute("update point_test pt set pt.coords=(select ST_GeomFromText(geomText) from temp_point_test tpt "+
                     "where pt.id=tpt.id)")

conn.execute("drop table temp_point_test")   

conn.close()
```